# Giving an object random stats

Tags: java, random

I've been wanting to make a text rpg for awhile now, but finally got around to starting making some objects and classes for a small prototype. I want to make a bunch of enemies, but without imputing stats for all of them individually, I decided to use java util.Random in order to generate a random int between 1-100 but when I look at the objects integers in my main test file theyre all 0. The l(); method is just a method i made without a printout in it with an object to save me some time. The stat value will give me a random number but the `l(goblin.health);` remains 0. Any advice on how to solve this?

```
Random stats = new Random(); 
int stat = stats.nextInt(100);
l(stat);

enemies goblin = new enemies(stat,stat,stat,stat);
l(goblin.health);
```

Comment: Either the constructor of `enemies` isn't correctly setting the fields, `l()` doesn't print out correctly, or `stats.nextInt` randomly happens to return 0 every time you run it.

Comment: I got it! it was a problem with my constructor! 
`public enemies(int health, int magic, int attack, int defense)
    {
        super(health, magic, attack, defense);
       
    }`

I had forgotten to add the ints into the `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

`stats.nextInt(100)` means integers [0,100) "0" inclusive, "100" excusive. so it should be `stats.nextInt(100) + 1`

```
Random stats = new Random(); 
int health= stats.nextInt(100) + 1; 
int magic= stats.nextInt(100) + 1; 
int attack= stats.nextInt(100) + 1;
int defense= stats.nextInt(100) + 1; 

enemies goblin = new enemies(health, magic, attack, defense); // enemies: class name should start with uppercase letter as "Enemies"
System.out.println(goblin.health);
System.out.println(magic.health);
System.out.println(attack.health);
System.out.println(defense.health);
```